# Views displays different component based on configuration

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing

I would like to know if there is a design pattern that would help me to build views differently based on some configuration parameters.  For exemple if configuration 1 is enabled then some components are displayed but if configuration 2 is enabled those component are not visible, or on configuration 3 I can display 2 of these component.
T

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by showing different "cards" using CardLayout. See [How to Use CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).